# Why can I get a valid url from getClass().getResource(), but the url that is returned creates a file that doesn't exist

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, file, aws-lambda, getresource

I am trying to load some data into an AWS lambda and am using getClass().getResource() to do so.  This returns a nice URL that in logs seemingly prints out a plausible url; however, when I try and make a file based on that path, I get a file that when I call .exists() returns false.

If I run the code bellow, the first print statement gives "returns exists: false"

Meanwhile, the second print statement gives something around the lines of "test path: /file:/var/task/lib/MyLambda-1.0.jar!/com/my/package/folders/file.end

```
File test = new File(cFile);
System.out.println("exists: " + test.exists());
System.out.println("test path: " + test.getAbsolutePath());
```

Not sure why this would be.  If Java finds a file, then I would assume that the file exists...

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Does the file exist or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: don't assume that the "path" of a URL is a file system pathname.

---

> I am trying to load some data into an AWS lambda and am using getClass().getResource() to do so. This returns a nice URL that in logs seemingly prints out a plausible url;

Yes.  (It would be nice if you showed us what the original URL looks like ... though I can guess.)

> However, when I try and make a file based on that path, I get a file that when I call .exists() returns false.

OK, unless the URL has the protocol "file:", I would NOT expect that to work.

The path in a URL is a path that is intended for the protocol handler to resolve.   The idea is that you use `URL::openStream` to open a stream to the resource named by the URL and then read it.  The protocol handler takes care of interpreting the path (etc) and setting up the stream.

- For a "file:" URL, the protocol handler will resolve the path in the file system, and provide you a stream to read the file.
- For a "http:" URL, the protocol handler establishes a  connection to the server, sends a GET request, and returns you a stream to read the response body.
- For a "jar:" URL, the protocol handler opens the JAR file, finds the entry within the JAR file, and hands you a stream to read it.
- And so on.

If you look at these, it is only in the "file:" case that there is a reasonable expectation that treating the path component of the URL as a file system pathname could work.

---

Looking at the pathname in your question:

```
file:/var/task/lib/MyLambda-1.0.jar!/com/my/package/folders/file.end
```

I surmise that the original URL was:

```
jar:file:/var/task/lib/MyLambda-1.0.jar!/com/my/package/folders/file.end
```

So what that says to the "jar:" protocol handler is:

1. Find the resource identified by the URL "file:/var/task/lib/MyLambda-1.0.jar"
2. Open it as a JAR file stream
3. Find the entry "/com/my/package/folders/file.end" in the JAR file's namespace
4. Open a stream to read that entry's content.

The JAR file protocol handler knows how to do that.  But (clearly) the `File` class doesn't ... because that "path" is not a file system pathname.

---

How you solve this depends on what you really need.

- If you just need a stream to read the resource, use `getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)` instead.
- If it must be a file in the file system, you may have to get hold of the stream (see above), copy it to a temporary file, and use a `File` for the temporary file.

If you are doing the because you want to write to the "file", I would suggest that you give up on that idea.  It is a bad idea for an application to try to update its resources.  And in some cases it simply won't / cannot work.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  I need it to be a file due to an API I am using, but I only need to read, so I will try your second suggestion.  If it works I will mark as correct and whatnot.  Also I cannot send the original URL for NDA related reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Is your File test = new File(cFile), Is your cFile made correctly with a proper path? Maybe the last print statement is just picking up on the incorrect path you made? But in reality you don't actually have a file there. Have you checked manually?

Comment: Do you have read and write privileges, are your backslashes double backslashes?